# SQL Query scenario

Tags: sql, database, oracle, hive

I have a SQL scenario. Could you please help me with the solutions for the same?

I have 2 Tables Account & Credit_Score, with the schema as below.

```
    -------------
    Account Table
    -------------
    Account_Number  Score
    A1              600
    A2              600
    B1              700
    B2              700
    B3              700
    C1              800
    C2              800

    -------------------
    Credit_Score Table
    -------------------
    Score          Balance
    600            1000
    700            6000
    800            8000
```

Now, I want a query which can give me a output as shown below. The balance amount gets splitted amongst the Account Holders having similar Score.

```
    ------------------------------
    Account_Number   |     Balance
    ------------------------------
    A1                     500
    A2                     500
    B1                     2000
    B2                     2000
    B3                     2000
    C1                     4000
    C2                     4000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select a.*,
       cs.balance / count(*) over (partition by cs.score) as balance
from account a join
     credit_score cs
     on cs.score = a.score;
```

Answer (score 1):

the below queries might be helpful to you,

hive way of @Gordon answer.

```
set hive.cli.print.header=true;
use hive_db;
create table if not exists account_table(account_number string,score string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile;

insert overwrite table account_table values ("A1","600"),("A2","600"),("B1","700"),("B2","700"),("B3","700"),("C1","800"),("C2","800")

create table if not exists credit_score ( score string, balance string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile;

insert overwrite table credit_score values ("600","1000"),("700","6000"),("800","8000")


select a.*,
       cs.balance / count(*) over (partition by cs.score) as balance
from account_table a join
     credit_score cs
     on cs.score = a.score;

'''
a.account_number a.score balance
A1               600     500.0
A2               600     500.0
B1               700     2000.0
B2               700     2000.0
B3               700     2000.0
C1               800     4000.0
C2               800     4000.0
'''
```